# Why won't Java compile this code?

Tags: java, class, abstract-class, abstract

I have some code like this:

```
abstract class ExampleOne {
   int dataOne = 1000;

   abstract void display();
}

class ExampleTwo extends ExampleOne {
   int dataTwo;

   ExampleTwo(int varOne) {
      dataTwo = varOne;
   }

   public void disp() {
      System.out.println("Testing");
   }

   public void display() {
      System.out.println(dataOne);
   }
}

class Example {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      ExampleOne obj = new ExampleTwo(20);
      obj.disp();
      obj.display();
   }
}
```

When I compile this, I get an error:

```
                obj.disp(); 
                     ^
  symbol:   method disp()
  location: variable obj of type ExampleOne
```

Why does this happen?

I'm assigning the instance of `ExampleTwo` to `ExampleOne`, why doesn't Java choose the `ExampleOne` instance instead of `ExampleTwo`?

The same concept works in terms of `dynamic polymorphism`!

Why is this so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since type of `obj` is `ExampleOne`, the compiler will search for the method you invoke on `obj` in `ExampleOne` class, and if it can't find, it will throw an error.

> why doesn't Java choose the ExampleOne instance instead of ExampleTwo?

That is because the *compile-time check* is done on the basis of *reference type* rather than the *actual object type*. And then the actual method invoked at runtime is decided on the basis of the *actual object* being referenced. This is what we call ***Dynamic Dispatch*** of method invocation.

You can add an abstract `disp()` method to your `ExampleOne` class, just to make sure, the compiler is happy with the invocation.

```
abstract class ExampleOne{ 
    int dataOne=1000; 
    abstract void display(); 
    abstract void disp();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your methods are only defined in `ExampleTwo`, but not `ExampleOne`.  This would cause the compilation error.

Comment: that's not correct..at **run time** it would be `ExampleTwo`..The error is because the compiler was not able to find the method at compile time

Answer (score 1):

Your object type is `ExampleOne`. Even if you created an instance of `ExampleTwo` the object type (i.e. method and members) known to the compiler is `ExampleOne` which do not have disp() declared.

You should declare an abstract method `disp()` in `ExampleOne` if you want it to be used in a polymorphic manner

Answer (score 1):

Base class object can access only its own class `Methods`. But `disp()` is not its method. So that's why you get the error.

to avoid error you can do this :

```
ExampleTwo obj=new ExampleTwo(20); 
                  obj.disp(); 
                  obj.display();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well,

The concept behind is that by this java contruct, you will invoke methods of ExampleOne with version of ExampleTwo.

means, you are allowed to invoke methods of reference variable type only (in your case it is ExampleOne ). But the version of method invoked will be of underlying object type(i.e. ExampleTwo). and it is facilitated by polymorphism.

Worth to mention here is that, you can assign object to any reference variables of its type or any its superclass, up in the hierarchy.